# Using AJAX to send to form data to PHP script and bring up success notification without refreshing the page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

Just to preface, I am very new to coding.

I'm working on a contact form for a website and I want, when the user submits the form, the data to be sent to my PHP script that sends an email, and then a notification bar to appear confirming the submission.

As of right now, when I press submit, the form does nothing.

- The bar is created already and is contained in a seperate function
- The form works if I let the page refresh normally
- I've tested it on and off the server already

```
function successHeader() {
    //jQuery for the confirmation box
    $(".submittedBox").css("display", "block"); //Displays Pop-Up
    $(".form_header").css("display", "none"); //Removes Contact Us      
}

function formSubmit() {

    $(".contact_form").submit(function(event) { //Submit Handler

        var $form = $(this), //Get the action attribute
            url = $form.attr('action');

        var post = $.post(url, $form.serialize());

        post.done(function() { //When the function is successfully submitted
            successHeader();
        });
    });

}
```

This is where the function is called (the error handling works)

```
//If the form has no errors
        if (error == 0) {
            formSubmit();
        }
```

The PHP script is named: form_processing.php

Expected: Form submits, and pop-up appears
Actual: Nothing

Comment: A PHP script cannot call a jQuery function, your comment makes me think you don't understand the life cycle of your application.  Show the code where you think you are calling the function

Comment: How are you calling `formSubmit()`?

Comment: Do you have more than one `.contact_form`? `$(".contact_form").serialize()` will serialize the first one, not the one the user is submitting. Use `$form.serialize()` to get the current form.

Comment: @Jameson2012 Sorry that was a comment from an earlier version of the code, when I was initially learning PHP, I forgot to remove it. The only script only processes the data and then sends an email, all of which works. I'm trying to determine why the code within formSubmit() isn't doing anything.

Comment: You should use `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the normal form submission.

Comment: @Barmar, after the error handling, I use this: if (error == 0) {
   formSubmit();
  }

Comment: You shouldn't call `.hover()` and `.click()` every time the form is submitted. You'll get multiple event handlers added to the popupClose buttons.

Comment: calling `formSubmit()` doesn't submit the form. It just adds an event handler that submits the form the next time the user clicks on the submit button.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, I've solved it